# (RT_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND) unset. Message: RT Library

Tags: ros, ros-lunar, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to follow the ROS tutorial and create my own package. I see the following error when I try to invoke catkin_make:

```
Base path: /home/parth/dev/ros
Source space: /home/parth/dev/ros/src
Build space: /home/parth/dev/ros/build
Devel space: /home/parth/dev/ros/devel
Install space: /home/parth/dev/ros/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/parth/dev/ros/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/parth/dev/ros/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/parth/dev/ros/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/parth/dev/ros/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/parth/dev/ros/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/lunar
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/lunar
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /home/parth/anaconda3/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/parth/dev/ros/build/test_results
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/gmock': gmock will be built
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gmock': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /home/parth/anaconda3/bin/nosetests
CMake Error at /opt/ros/lunar/share/catkin/cmake/assert.cmake:17 (message):
  

  Assertion failed: check for file existence, but filename
  (RT_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND) unset.  Message: RT Library

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/lunar/share/catkin/cmake/tools/rt.cmake:42 (assert_file_exists)
  /opt/ros/lunar/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:147 (include)
  /opt/ros/lunar/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:52 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/parth/dev/ros/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/parth/dev/ros/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297453/(rt_library-notfound)-unset.--message:-rt-library/) by [jitsunen](https://answers.ros.org/users/36478/jitsunen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2018-07-15

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-15**:
When you're referring to a tutorial or some other source, please include a link to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The only time I've seen this error, cleaning my workspace fixed it. I'd also recommend using catkin tools (i.e., run `catkin build` instead of `catkin_make`).

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2018-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Tom Moore, thanks for the tip!
In order to make catkin build work, I discovered that some of the python modules were missing. I had to install catkin_tools, trollius and catkin build worked. I also had to comment out the RT_LIBRARY check in /opt/ros/lunar/share/catkin/cmake/tools/rt.cmake. I read on some other post that this dependency was not required to build packages (not sure if that's true, but I decided to give it a try).

I also tried catkin_make after catkin build and that worked as well. So, I guess installing the missing python modules did the trick.

Thanks to everyone for their comments!. I appreciate the quick turn around time.

---

Originally posted by [jitsunen](https://answers.ros.org/users/36478/jitsunen/) with karma: 31 on 2018-07-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-08-08**:
Glad that you got it working, although having to modify `rt.cmake` doesn't sounds a right, permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

Remove the CMakeLists.txt on your catkin workspace for catkin_make.

ex) `$ rm -rf ${CATKIN_PATH}/src/CMakeList.txt`

And, rebuild it.

`$ cd ${CATKIN_PATH}`
`$ catkin_make`

---

Originally posted by [harderthan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34798/harderthan/) with karma: 98 on 2019-01-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1